# Forward declaration of class used in function template is not compiled

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, forward-declaration

I have the following code which is not compiled with gcc, but compiles perfectly with MSVC.

```
class B;

class A
{
    B *_parent;

public:

    template <typename T>
    void Do(T val)
    {
        _parent->DoB(val);
    }

    A(B *parent)
        :   _parent(parent)
    {
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:

    B()
        : A(nullptr)
    {
    }

    void DoB(int val)
    {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(&b);
    a.Do(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error is as follows:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void A::Do(T)’:
prog.cpp:15:10: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class B’
   _parent->DoB(val);
          ^~
prog.cpp:4:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class B’
 class B;
       ^
```

According to the similar posts, that behaviour of gcc is correct due to paragraph 14.6.9 of the Standard. But that is counterintuitive since templates should be instantiated only where used. And the only usage occurs after all classes have been defined.

My question is what are the workarounds for this issue? Because using the member template is really convenient in this case. Maybe the problem is with the architecture or something else?

Comment: The design is definitely strange. Maybe you would want to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: 14.6.9 of what version of the Standard? In any case, yes, anything in a template definition that is not "dependent" on a template parameter must be well-formed at the template definition even if never instantiated, and here the `_parent->DoB` subexpression violates that rule.

Comment: I’ve fixed the terminology in the title since, in this instance, the distinction is highly relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra layer:

```
class A
{
    B *_parent;

private:
    template <typename TB, typename T>
    static void CallDoB(TB* b, T&& val) {
        b->DoB(std::forward<T>(val));
    }
public:

    template <typename T>
    void Do(T val)
    {
        CallDoB(_parent, val);
    }

    A(B *parent) : _parent(parent) {}
};
```

now `b->` is dependent of template and is postponed until real instantiation.

Comment: actually, I've came up with a similar solution:

`template <typename T, typename ThisClass = A>
void Do(T val)
{
    static_cast<ThisClass *> (this)->_parent->DoB(val);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the parts of `A` that rely on `B` to be known, but define them later. The declaration then looks like this

```
class B;

class A
{
    B *_parent;

    public:
        template <typename T> void Do(T val); /* (see below) */
        A(B *parent) :   _parent(parent) {}
};
```

then comes the definition of `B`

```
class B : public A { /* As before. */ };
```

and finally you define the missing pieces

```
template <typename T> void A::Do(T val)
{
    _parent->DoB(val); /* Fine, B is known. */
}
```

As a side note, the original code compiled with just a warning using gcc 8.